# impossible to change the home directory of jupyter notebook on Mac

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

OK, I understand that I can `import os` to change the working directory for each project, however, what I want is to change the start location of `http://localhost:8888/tree`

The current location is `/Users/myname`, how can I change to another directory? I googled a lot, and I did the following steps:

Terminal typing in:

```
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/Users/yourname/folder1/folder2/
```

This works for the time, but it returns to the `/Users/myname` again when restarting the notebook.

Some suggest that to find the `ipython_notebook_config.py` to change the following (`line 203'):

```
c.NotebookApp.ipython_dir = 'Users/myname/Documents/my folder'
```

It, however, did not work.

Comment: you can go to the preferred location and start your jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1):

if you cd into the location you want to be, then launch jupyter notebook, you should achieve what you want:

```
$ cd to /preferred location/
.../preferred location $ jupyter notebook
```

on mac OSX, if you cd to `/Volumes/`, you can access virtually any useful place on your directory tree, from the `jupyter home page`

Answer (score 1):

I got a turnaround solution that to save the path as a bookmark of a web in chrome tag and whenever I enter the root of jupyter notebook. I know it's stupid but it did work... I have tried your answers above but not really work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you're looking for, but you could set up an alias in bash_profile.

For example:

```
$ nano ~/.bash_profile
alias jupe_shtct='jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/Users/yourname/folder1/folder2/'
```

See https://jonsuh.com/blog/bash-command-line-shortcuts/ for further information.

Answer (score 0):

There is `c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir` option in `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file. I've been using it with Jupyter Notebook without any issues. Refer to [Jupyter manual](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html) for more details.

`c.NotebookApp.ipython_dir` is a deprecated option.